# ionic cordova plugin add ERROR

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, plugins

When run this command:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="google-api-key" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="google-api-key"
```

The ERROR occurs:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-googlemaps" for android
```

> Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-googlemaps': Error: ENOENT: no such
>   file or directory, open
>   '/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'

Comment: Which Android CLI version you are using for this project ?

Comment: cordova-android@~7.0.0

Comment: please check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51113465/541462

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have sometimes the same problem, have open sublime or something like notepad?

if you have opened some notepad, check if exists the android directory and click inside of him(sometimes dont remove this directory with the notepad opened)

if dont exists the directory, the problem is easy you dont have the directory. You must to do these commands inside ionic proyect.

For ionic:

```
ionic platflorm remove android
ionic platform add android
```

For cordova cli:

```
ionic cordova platflorm remove android
ionic cordova platform add android
```

For check ionic version inside proyect:

ionic info

Greetings dherediat

Comment: Hi, dherediat, I followed your command, when I run "ionic cordova platform add android", there is another error: Failed to install 'com.synconset.imagepicker':

Comment: Installing "com.synconset.imagepicker" for android

Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...

Failed to install 'com.synconset.imagepicker': Error: Uh oh!
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'

Comment: looks like that dont exists android manifest, i'll try open with android studio for another problem with gradle or something...

Comment: I work on MAC mini, need use google map in my project, I don't know the android thing.

Comment: Then it will show me the error "missing variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID". I removed Android and add android@6.4.0, now android is OK, while it stuck at ios. The message is as below: "Plugin "cordova-plugin-googlemaps" already installed on android.

Installing "cordova-plugin-googlemaps" for ios

apple-xcode version check failed ("/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/platforms/ios/cordova/apple_xcode_version"), continuing anyways.

apple-ios version check failed ("/Users/xxx/Desktop/xxx/platforms/ios/cordova/apple_ios_version"), continuing anyways."

Comment: XCode Version 9.3 (9E145)

Comment: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-platform-ios-failed-for-cordova-ios-3-9-2/36164/9, the solution is rm -rf ~/.cordova

Comment: no such .cordova file in my home or project directory.

Comment: try install cocoapods with: sudo gem install cocoapods and try again

Comment: It doesn't work, still stuck at "apple-ios version check failed" and "apple-xcode version check failed".

Comment: have apple id and dev team for this app?

Comment: Hi, dherediat, my teammate told me maybe it is the problem with apple id and dev team, and no need to add platform for this app. At last, I followed this tutorial https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/ to integrate google map into my app. And use "ionic serve" to view the result on browser. This is the first time I use ionic, so I don't know the platform thing, thank you so much to teach me patiently.

Comment: you're welcome, i followed that tutorial and is a good option, if have more problems about ionic email me

Answer (score 0):

As per Cordova Android CLI version 7.0.0 release note you need to change your **AndroidManifest.xml** path as mention below

> This may affect plugin.xml files and config.xml files that use
>   edit-config, and make it so plugins that use edit-config will not be
>   able to be compatible with both Android 6.x and Android 7.x. To fix
>   this issue, please do the following in your XML files:

```
<!-- An existing config.xml -->
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">

<!-- needs to change to -->
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
```

Check this official release note for [Cordova Android CLI 7.0.0 Release Note](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html).

Hope this will helps to solve your problem

Comment: Hi, is this "config.xml" file the one in my project folder? Or where can I find this file? There is no such line in the config.xml file.