# Google Plus Plugin and Push Notification Plugin conflict on PhoneGap Build, Build failed

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I need to use google plus plugin along with the push notification plugin
`<plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm" spec="5.2.1"></plugin>`, but using both of them build gives error : `Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin'] > For input string: "+"`

When I use 5.3.0 of googleplus plugin then it works and build succeeds, but then on sending notifications a pop up appears in my mobile &saying **App has stopped ...Close App.**

**UPDATE :** 
**config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<widget id="com.phonegap.myapp1" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>My App1</name>
    <description>
       MyApp
    </description>


        <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
        <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
        <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" /> 
        <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />



        <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-8.0.0' />

        <preference name='pgb-builder-version' value='2' />






        <hook src="scripts/cordova-google-services-version-gradle-fix.js" type="before_prepare" />



            <platform name="android">

                <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+" />

                <framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" />

            </platform>
```

> THIS removes the conflict error but when sending NOTIFICATION and instead of the notification a dialog appears in my  mobile which says App has stopped Close App

```
        <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm" spec="5.3.0"></plugin>
```

> so i am using this version which gives a nice notification

```
     <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googleplus" source="npm" spec="5.2.1"></plugin>    


        <platform name="android">   

            <resource-file src="app/google-services.json" target="app/google-services.json" />  

        </platform>     



         <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.10.5">     
OR
      <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.4.5">  
OR

    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.1.3"> 
            <param name="SENDER_ID" value="xxx" />
        </plugin>


            <content src="index.html" />    


    </widget>
```

Comment: what version of phonegap-plugin-push are you using?

Comment: @jcesarmobile : <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="2.1.3"> 
   <param name="SENDER_ID" value="xxxxx" />
  </plugin>

Comment: @jcesarmobile : On using 1.4.5 of push plugin Build says : Error :  
Script '/phonegap-plugin-push/myapp-push.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> /app/AndroidManifest.xml (No such file or directory)

Comment: @jcesarmobile : please see the update in my post, i have posted my config.xml file

Comment: @jcesarmobile : can you please suggest me some solution ?

Comment: @jcesarmobile: i have mentioned the version as per your question and also the config.xml code in my post update