# Cordova AndroidManifest.xml Doesn't Exist w/ 7.0 Plugin Compatibility

Tags: android, cordova

When installing a plugin or just adding the 7.0/7.1 Android platform to a Cordova project the system will return an error `failed to install 'plugin name': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '...application directory.../platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'` *despite* the plugin never referencing the legacy file location.

The plugin has had it's edit-config `AndroidManifest.xml` target switched to `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` as per the Cordova blog post [here](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html) but it still causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to *also* move any references to the root `res` directory to `app/src/main/res` in addition to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For example, if you have a reference in your apps main `config.xml` file like

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification-icon.png" 
    target="res/drawable/notification_icon.png" />
```

then the `target` needs to be changed to look like

```
<resource-file src="resources/android/notification-icon.png" 
    target="app/src/main/res/drawable/notification_icon.png" />
```

in order to work on `cordova-android@7.0.0` or above.

The most likely answer to this same question for most people is here:
[Cordova does not create AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926796/cordova-does-not-create-androidmanifest-xml) however, this answer is the only thing that worked on my project to solve the issue.

Credit for this discovery is due to @ryanwilliams' comment on @jcesarmobile's answer to the question linked above, highlighting that

> If you have a 'res' folder in the root of your project you will still get this error even after updating the path inside plugin.xml (Due to Eclipse project detection)