# Cordova 8, Android 7.1.0, can't install any plugins

Tags: android, cordova

Every plugin I try to install throws an error saying it can't find the manifest.  And it's true, the file isn't there.  I am trying to upgrade off 6.4 as 6.4 doesn't seem to support 64bit CPUs on Android without making manual changes to the build manifest.

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geolocation': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-file': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\..\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-google-analytics': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-inappbrowser': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-whitelist': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-network-information': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-sqlite-storage': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-android-permissions': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-statusbar': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-device': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

`Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-image-picker': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\...\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'`

How do I solve these errors?

Comment: see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926796/cordova-does-not-create-androidmanifest-xml/47927193#47927193

Comment: Trouble is these are mostly apache provided plugins.  Very troubling if they aren't updated by the people that updated cordova

Comment: You didn't read my updated answer or you didn't understand it. All the apache provided plugins work fine on cordova-android 7.1.0. The problem is one of the 3rd party plugins using source-file tag for copying images and making cordova crazy. One of them is `cordova-plugin-image-picker`, remove that, remove cordova-android and add it again and see what happens.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Yes image picker was bad.  Thank you

Comment: @TrevorD - if you are still looking for a proper `cordova-plugin-image-picker` plugin, you can use this one https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/ImagePicker. I believe it is basically the same, but it has the properly adjusted tags.

Comment: @AngelTodorov Thank you.  I will start watching that one and https://github.com/DmcSDK/cordova-plugin-mediaPicker

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got the answer, the amazing community made a script to patch it.

Create a script in your scripts folder called

patch-android-studio-check.js

Put this inside it

```
/**
 * This hook overrides a function check at runtime. Currently, cordova-android 7+ incorrectly detects that we are using
 * an eclipse style project. This causes a lot of plugins to fail at install time due to paths actually being setup
 * for an Android Studio project. Some plugins choose to install things into 'platforms/android/libs' which makes
 * this original function assume it is an ecplise project.
 */
module.exports = function(context) {
  if (context.opts.cordova.platforms.indexOf('android') < 0) {
    return;
  }

  const path = context.requireCordovaModule('path');
  const androidStudioPath = path.join(context.opts.projectRoot, 'platforms/android/cordova/lib/AndroidStudio');
  const androidStudio = context.requireCordovaModule(androidStudioPath);
  androidStudio.isAndroidStudioProject = function() {  return true; };
};
```

Then add these hooks

```
<platform name="android">
   <hook src="scripts/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_plugin_install" />
   <hook src="scripts/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_plugin_install" />
   <hook src="scripts/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_plugin_add" />
   <hook src="scripts/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_build" />
   <hook src="scripts/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_run" />
   <hook src="scripts/patch-android-studio-check.js" type="before_plugin_rm" />
</platform>
```

Next, delete your plugins and platforms folder.  Then run `cordova platform add android` and this will recreate the platform and add the plugins correctly.

Second part is don't use the image picker plugin.

Update March 2019 -  As of Cordova Android verison 8, this appears to be no longer required and will actually cause problems.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue with cordova-android 7 and 8.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs ([cordova android 7](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/12/04/cordova-android-7.0.0.html), file path of `AndroidManifest.xml`has changed. So you have to update all of your plugins to a version that support android 7 !

Answer (score 0):

On your config.xml file just under

```
<platform name="android">
```

Add this line

```
<resource-file src="platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" target="AndroidManifest.xml" />
```