# No such file AndroidManifest.xml with cordova >= 7

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have an ionic project and I need to use [Batch](https://batch.com/doc/cordova/sdk-integration.html).
In order to use Batch in the last version (2.0.0), I should update my `cordova-android` to `>=7.0.0`.

But the problem is that if I update that dependency to the required version, all the other plugins fails because they not support that `cordova-android` version yet.

Basically, it says that `AndroidManifest.xml` file is not found:

```
(node:8420) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/<mypath>/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

if I do this steps:

1. remove the android platform (`cordova platform remove android`).
2. remove node_modules and plugins (`rm -rf /node_modules /plugins`).
3. remove the plugins entries in the `packaje.json` and in `config.xml`.
4. add android platform again (`cordova platform add android`).

The android platform is created.
BUT, if I try to add the batch plugin I have the same error (when they said they support `cordova-android >= 7` only):

```
ionic cordova plugin add com.batch.cordova
> cordova plugin add com.batch.cordova --save
Installing "com.batch.cordova" for android

Failed to install 'com.batch.cordova': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/<mypath>/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

I mentioned this plugin for example because they say that they ONLY support `cordova-android >= 7` but it's happening with ALL the cordova plugins in my case.

I could use a minor version of Batch plugin (`1.7.4`) that is compatible with older version `cordova-android`. **But that version of Batch has not got the In app messaging feature and it's required in my case. That version only has Push notifications and events tracking** :/

This is my ionic info:

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.10
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.1
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
    Node              : v6.14.3
    npm               : 4.6.1 
    OS                : Linux 4.4

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : /home/ivan/Android

Misc:

    backend : legacy
```

Any solution for this? I can't find any solution. People have this error with specific plugins but in my case it's happening with all the plugins!

Thanks!

Comment: See my answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926796/cordova-does-not-create-androidmanifest-xml/47927193#47927193

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you need to use "ionic cordova plugin add yourpluginname --nofetch" to install the plugins in Cordova7. It is defined in the cordova 7 documentation. Please refer below link for more details:
https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html

It will be like this

```
ionic cordova plugin add com.batch.cordova --nofetch
```