# Cordova plugin add fails for ENOENT on AndroidManifest

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-manifest, enoent

I've developed a custom plugin for a cordova application and trying to test it out with the latest cordova Android platform version.

Whenever I run:

```
cordova plugin add ../my-plugin
cordova platform add android
```

or

```
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add ../my-plugin
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to install 'com.my.plugin': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/project/my-application/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
```

This is the content of my `plugin.xml` file for what concerns the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<config-file target="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</config-file>
```

I've already seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47927193/3119050) which is pretty commonly shared throughout different resources and websites I visited but is not helping me since I'm already using `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` after updating from `android@6.4.0` to `android@7.0.0`.

---

My environment is:

- macOS
- `cordova@8.1.2`
- `android@7.1.1`

Note: As of now I made it work by using `android@6.4.0` but I'd like to understand how to make it work with newer platform versions.